# Firefox keeping downloaded filed in .part extension

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, download, webdriver

Whenever I attempt downloading files through firefox (using a ff profile with automatic download enabled for certain file types (pdf) to a pre-defined folder) the file remain in .part extension even though they have to be set to their initial extension. Is there something I should configure in the firefox profile or any other way I could make firefox rename downloaded files properly?

Profile configuration is very straightforward:
`profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2); profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",Config.dlFolder);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pdf");`

Comment: `.part` is a partially downloaded file if I'm not mistaken. If it stays named as `.part` - this could mean that the file wasn't completely downloaded. My guess is - you should wait for it to be downloaded completely before closing the browser session.

Comment: "part" extension is given to files that are in the processes of downloading. Most likely is was it was derived for the "multipart/form-data" HTML datatype.

Comment: I might be checking for the file too early, gonna check for the specific extension and see what happens.

Comment: Gave it all another try. The file is downloaded completely, but firefox doesn't handle it as a donwload-completed file and rename it (remove the '.part' from the filename).